# Structure from Motion using Emgu

Tags: c#, opencv, 3d

I have been trying to get my mind around how to do structure from motion using Emgu (C# openCV wrapper) and images extracted from a monocular video, but I find most of the papers on the subject to be too theoretical and written in a mathematical language I am not familiar with.

I have been able to track 2D feature points pretty accurately, although I still got some outliers, and now need to find the camera location and angle given array pairs of the 2D feature points (current and next frame). I understand I probably need to use some kind of RANSAC algorithm to get the best match from a set of these feature points.

How would one proceed to solve this using Emgu and C#?

Comment: Do you want to recover structure from pairwise images or do you want to use an algorithm that consumes all images at once? Is the calibration of your camera known? Are you familiar with triangulation when the extrinsic camera parameters are known?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using standard GoPro cameras, so calibration data should be available. I think pairwise images (by that I mean current and next frame, not a stereo rig) would be more practical as the video is quite long. It might be helpful to know I need to track a road recorded from a car mounted camera, and the video will typically be about one hour long at 60FPS, so probably there would be more than 200.000 frames. Accuracy is more important than processing speed, as the video is pre-recorded.

Comment: This seems like a quite challenging task. Could be a small PhD thesis. I hope you are aware of that. There is a [computervision textbook](http://szeliski.org/Book/) that has a whole chapter dedicated to structure from motion, explaining different algorithms. Especially chapter 7.2 should be interesting to you.

Comment: Thank you sietschie, and yes, I know it is a quite involving task, spent a lot of time on this already. Unfortunately most books and papers on the subject are very theoretical, including the one you mention here. And I was hoping OpenCV has some useful methods for the stage of finding the camera location and translation from tracked points.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no such functions in OpenCV. But there are libraries available. Check the wikipedia article for structure from motion.